# Procedure to construct number rings of number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I need a good reference to learn the procedure of constructing number rings of number fields. I am currently reading Daniel Marcus, the procedure given there is not getting clear and I am finding it a little confusing. Can anyone refer me a material, where this proofs are presented clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you expect but

- From the primitive element theorem find $c\in K$ such that $K=Q(c)$. Let $m$ be the product of denominators of its minimal polynomial and $a=mc$. Then $a\in O_K$ such that $K=Q(a)$.
- Show that $n O_K\subset Z[a]$ where $n=Disc(Z[a])= |O_K/Z[a]|^2 Disc(O_K)=\det(Tr(a^i a^j))$
- $n^{-1} Z[a]/Z[a]$ is a finite group, pick a representative $b_j$ of all its element to find which ones are algebraic integers (checking if $\det(xI-B_j)\in Z[x]$ where $B_j$ is the matrix of the multiplication by $b_j$ in the $[K:Q]$ dimensional $Q$-vector space $Q[a]$), you'll have $$O_K= \bigcup_{b_j\in O_K} (b_j+Z[a])$$
- Not too hard to find a $Z$-module basis of $O_K$ from there.

Comment: Not quite sure about the 2nd and 3rd point's proofs.. My point was I know the proof for quadratic number field clearly, but I did not understand the proof about other number rings, for instance cubic number ring $\mathbb{Z}[a^{1/3}]$ or cyclotomic number rings $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_r]$, was asking about reading materials for that..